# How to signOut from an app using gapi without needing to click on a button

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api-js-client

I'm developping a web app for an association, and for many reasons we wanted to used the Auth2 api of Google.

So, here's how our loggin process works:

- The user clicks on the google sign-in button
- The token is sent to a page to check if it's valid, and if the user already exists in the DB
- If the token is valid, then autorise the user
- If the user doesn't exist, then logout the user from the Google App

Here's a simplified version of my token verification page, assuming that the user doesn't exist (i skipped the php to check that, and just inserted what the php would echo):

```
<script>
    function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }

    function loadGapi() {
        gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            gapi.auth2.init();
        });
    }
</script>

<a href="#" id="logoutButton" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>     

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<script>
    loadGapi();
    signOut();
</script>
```

When the page loads, I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthInstance' of undefined
    at signOut   // On line 3
```

note that the logoutButton is just for test purposes, and works perfectly fine when clicked, but I really can't figure out how to disconnect the user without needing him to interact with anything.

(Thanks for taking the time to read this, i've been stuck on this for like 3 hours ^^)

Comment: gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() this gapi may not be initialized. Please check may be with a settimeout

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in case anyone have the same issue, just define a function to execute at the end of loading as an attribute in body

```
<body onload="functionToCall()">
</body>
```